Importing content but it displays that it already exists
I have been trying to import a basic, exported Wordpress content XML file. What I'm trying to do is add a blog post from one site to another. When I try to import the XML document it simply states that all the pages already exist and nothing is done and I am not able to view it. It does not exist already.

You'll have to ask the WordPress Import plugin support about this, as it's not a WordPress Development question.
